# Magento 1.9 product import xlsx to csv

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import

I am trying to write a module that converts the given Xls file to default Magento CSV format? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: This comment is not much use but we wrote a seperate PHP script to covert the CSV that our system exported to a csv that we would import via magmi.  Just seemed better to keep it outside of magento

Comment: @PaddyD thanks man :) I have done this through a external PHP script, which is converting EXCEL to csv then imports .

Comment: @Radhu got any solution ?